# Show that the area bounded by the hyperbola and chord is equal to the area bounded by the hyperbola and another chord.

Tags: calculus, contest-math

I'm giving it a go on some Putnam problems just for fun and this one seems interesting but I can't visualize the problem. Can anyone explain the problem in layman terms and maybe draw it out?

**Problem:** Let $A$ and $B$ be points on the same branch of the hyperbola $xy=1$. Suppose that $P$ is a point lying between $A$ and $B$ on this hyperbola such that the area of the triangle $APB$ is as large as possible. Show that the region bounded by hyperbola and the chord $AP$ has the same ae as the region bounded by the hyperbola and the chord $PB$.

Answer (score 1):

**This is not the solution**
This is just the figure the OP asked for.

[image]

On the graph of $y=\frac1x$, there are two points $A$ and $B$. If $P$ is between $A,B$ and $P$ moves, say, from $A$ to $B$ then the area of the red triangle is changing, and at a certain place it must take its maximum. (The area is changing from zero to zero in a continuous fashion, without jumps.)

While $P$ moves from $A$ to be, the green and the blue areas are also changing. The problem is to show that the green area equals the blue area when the red area takes its maximum.

Comment: Awesome, thank you buddy! I'll have a go at this today, if I fail solving it I will come back :)